# how to send checkbox value 1 or 0 in database?

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

```
<input type="checkbox" name="chkbx" value="true" checked>

$data['active'] = $this->input->post('active');

        if($data['active'] ==  true){
            echo $data['active'] = 1 ;
        }
        else{
            echo $data['active'] = 0 ;
        }
```

It always put 0 value in database. I can't understand.
please help me to solve this problem.

Comment: if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
            $this->db->insert('data', $data);
        }

Answer (score 1):

> Checkboxes are posted only when they are checked.

Use [isset()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.isset.php)

Use proper checkbox name.

```
$data['active'] = $this->input->post('chkbx');
if (isset($data['active'])) {
 echo $data['active'] = 1;
}
else {
 echo $data['active'] = 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

According to docs "The main advantage of using the provided functions rather than fetching an item directly ($_POST['something']) is that the functions will check to see if the item is set and return false (boolean) if not".

try using

```
if($data['active'] !==  false){

        // Check box value is set check its value and insert in DB here
    }
    else{
       // Check box not set you can have your fall back method
    }
```

Comment: when we do this then it put only 1 i database

Comment: I have edited answer, thanks for info.

Answer (score 0):

Your checkbox name `name="chkbx"` and `$this->input->post('active')` is different. Use the same and check.

Comment: i can do but the same problem here

Comment: thnx my problem is solve